# PHP REGEX: how to pad numbers in the middle/end of a string

Tags: php, regex, zero-padding

i have a list of key=>value pairs from a JSON squirt.  i sorted the array and i'm left with the following (excerpted relevant cases because they go as high as 92):

```
dir1summary
dir10summary
dir1summarydue
dir10summarydue
directive1
directive10
directivecode1
directivecode10
```

what i need to do is:
1) place all the digits at the end and
2) pad them to 2 digits (01,02,&c)
so the list ends up looking like this:

```
directivesummary01
directivesummary10
directivesummarydue01
directivesummarydue10
directive01
directive10
directivecode01
directivecode10
```

i was hoping to do this with one REGEX statement given the obvious similarity in key names, but i got lost.  here's what i have so far:

```
dir((\d{1,2}(summary|summarydue))|((ective\d{1,2})|(ectivecode\d{1,2})))
```

...aaaand i'm lost what to do next.    how to move on?  is there a better *compact* way to do this?

EDIT:  this also means i have to replace 'dir' with 'directive'. it's implied in the result list, but i didnt' make a bullet item for it.  also, the REGEX is all i was able to build at [RegExer](https://regexr.com/).  thus the "lost what to do next" part.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/OtWHmC/2/ with a `preg_replacecallback` to trim the leading `0` on +10 integers. Also in the future a shared `regex101` or `regexer` link would be much more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Match but don't capture `dir`
- Match but don't capture the optional substring `ective`
- Retain zero or more non-digital characters immediately after `ective` as capture group #1 (this accounts for optional substrings like `summarydue`)
- Retain the whole integer as capture group #2
- Retain the remainder of the string as capture group #3

---

- In the custom function, hardcode `directive`, then append capture group #1 (which may be empty), then capture group #3 (might also be empty), finally left pad capture group #2 with a zero to a maximum length of 2-digits and append that value to the end of the string

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X6uGD))

```
$strings = [
    'dir1summary',
    'dir10summary',
    'dir1summarydue',
    'dir10summarydue',
    'directive1',
    'directive10',
    'directivecode1',
    'directivecode10',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/dir(?:ective)?(\D*)(\d+)(.*)/',
        function ($m) {
            return "directive{$m[1]}{$m[3]}" . str_pad($m[2], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        },
        $strings
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'directivesummary01',
  1 => 'directivesummary10',
  2 => 'directivesummarydue01',
  3 => 'directivesummarydue10',
  4 => 'directive01',
  5 => 'directive10',
  6 => 'directivecode01',
  7 => 'directivecode10',
)
```

---

Alternatively, you could parse the string with `sscanf()`, then print the isolated components in the desired format with `printf()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JOm6q))

```
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    sscanf($string, '%[^0-9]%d%s', $dir, $num, $str);
    printf("%s%s%02d\n", str_pad($dir, 9, 'ective'), $str, $num);
}
// same result strings as above
```

Comment: okay.  this is not only solved, but explained so clearly and simply that i learned even more than i came here to! @mickmackusa, your obvious mastery of regex is clear.  thank you for your time and effort.  VERY much appreciated.  wow...  :D

Comment: When you post a clear problem statement,  a sufficiently large sample set, a desired output, and a coding attempt; you have a complete question that is very attractive to answer.  I have no idea what a json squirt is, but that didn't matter because all of the logic was clearly expressed.  I am very happy to generously share my knowledge on questions that add value to Stackoverflow.

Comment: JSON squirt = a JSON array received via POST or GET.  too much William Gibson as a youth.  ;)